# Why does my QueryPath script result in "Creating default object from empty value" error?

Tags: php, web-scraping, querypath

I am trying to scrape a website to get some practice with [QueryPath](https://github.com/technosophos/querypath/).

Here is what I have so far, and gives me an error:

> **Creating default object from empty value**

Code:

```
// URL to scrape
$baseurl = 'http://some-site-with-a-table-of-items-that-contain-links.com';

// Get all rows from table
$rows = htmlqp($baseurl, '#items_table')->find('tr');

//initialize items array
$items = array();

// initilize counter
$i = 0;

// Iterate through rows of items
foreach($rows as $row) {

    // get the url for the item in this row
    $url = qp($row)->find('.link_txt a')->attr('href');

    // select all the info in the item detail box
    $item = htmlqp($url)->find('.item_detail_box');

    // assign the item attributes to an array
    $items[$i] = [

        // the qp item $row is from the info on the main table of items
        'img_thumb'     => qp($row)->find('.reflection')->attr('src'),
        'name'          => qp($row)->find('.link_txt a')->text(),
        'item_level'    => qp($row)->find('.col_center')->text(),
        'req_level'     => qp($row)->find('.col_right')->text(),
        'url'           => $url,

        // the qp item $item is from the actual item detail page
        //'img'         => qp($item)->find('.reflection')->attr('src'),
        //'is_unique'   => qp($item)->find('.unique')->text(),


    ];

    $i++;
}

$data = print_r($items, true);

return '<pre>' . $data . '</pre>';
```

The error will occur if I uncomment either of the `img` or `is_unique` array lines.

Everything else works and gives expected output when those lines are commented out.

Comment: I suddenly started to get this error too, outputting more information, I found it was related to QueryPath/DOMQuery.php line 186 where it says "$this->document->formatOutput = TRUE;" perhaps this means that "$this->document" wasn't created and assigning TRUE to formatOutput means it has to create a default object first...however WHY it happens, I don't know yet.

Comment: I found this discussion on this exact topic, probably this is useful to you: https://github.com/technosophos/querypath/issues/130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happened because QueryPath was getting nothing from the selector trying to get text from an anchor tag.

I was trying to get the text from a link/anchor from each table row.

However, the first row in my loop was a table header and not a row with any links.

Adding a check in the loop fixed my issue:

```
$url_ext = qp($row)->find('.ic_link_txt a')->attr('href');

    if ( $url_ext != NULL && $url_ext != "" ) {
```

Which was a stupid mistake on my part not knowing enough about QueryPath.

(Also related to github issue https://github.com/technosophos/querypath/issues/130 )

Comment: While you are right, it was your mistake the way Querypath has this implemented is highly anoying.
You can't even use "empty()" to check if the find is empty or not.